# Online Accounts - Linkedin

Tags: online-accounts

When trying to add Linkedin to online accounts, I keep getting

```
Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug report on Launchpad about this issue: Bug #1329629
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/account-plugins/+bug/1329629

Answer (score 2):

Linkedin updated *OAuth 2.0 Authorization* to enforce redirect URLs rule. It means each application key should have redirect URLs predefined. With any URL isn't listed with key, OAuth request will be rejected. Here is the message posted on top of [Linkedin developer page](https://developer.linkedin.com/):

> OAuth 2.0 Authorization issues?
>
> As previously announced, LinkedIn is now enforcing redirect URLs rule for OAuth 2.0 applications: [More information](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/register-your-oauth-2-redirect-urls). If you have any questions, please post to this thread in our forums: [Thread for questions](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/register-your-oauth-2-redirect-urls)

This is a workaround (with better privacy) till original developer update its app key links. You may create & use your own.

1. Login & Go to developer page: https://developer.linkedin.com/
2. In top right corner, Click on your login name → API keys
3. Add new application & login
4. Fill up form

   Default Scope: 'r_fullprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'r_network', 'w_messages', 'rw_nus'
   Redirect URLs: https://www.linkedin.com/
5. Put the new key in Linkedin plugin

   ```
    sudo nano /usr/share/accounts/providers/linkedin.provider
   ```

   Copy:

   API Key → `<setting name="ClientId">...</setting>`
   Secret Key → `<setting name="ClientSecret">...</setting>`

[image: linkedin plugin - error with original key]
[image: linkedin plugin - login with a new key]

Comment: Shows me the login screen now but when I enter my login info, it just kicks me back to Online Accounts

Comment: Started over from scratch and I was able to login and allow the application but now, none of my linkedin updates are showing.

Comment: @user286621, could I ask which app you are using? AFAIK key should list all sub domains needed by application.May be it require other subdomains of `linkedin.com` not just `www.`

Comment: using friends-app